# Implement From and Into for str, String, borrowed and owned

Tags: rust

I am trying to reduce the boilerplate in my code. I have tried to use Cow, Borrow or AsRef to combine these implementations together, but the compiler complains that Address does not implement the trait sized.

To implement all the cases &str vs String and Address vs &Address, my current code feels excessive

```
pub struct Address(String);

impl From<String> for Address {
    fn from(bytes: String) -> Self {
        Self(String::from_utf8(Vec::from(bytes)).unwrap())
    }
}

impl From<String> for &Address {
    fn from(bytes: String) -> Self {
        &Address(String::from_utf8(Vec::from(bytes)).unwrap())
    }
}

impl From<&str> for Address {
    fn from(str: &str) -> Self {
        Self(str.to_string())
    }
}

impl From<&str> for &Address {
    fn from(str: &str) -> Self {
        &Address(str.to_string())
    }
}

impl<'b> Into<&'b str> for Address {
    fn into(self) -> &'b str {
        self.0.as_str()
    }
}

impl<'b> Into<&'b str> for &Address {
    fn into(self) -> &'b str {
        self.0.as_str()
    }
}

impl<'b> Into<String> for Address {
    fn into(self) -> String {
        self.0.to_string()
    }
}

impl<'b> Into<String> for &Address {
    fn into(self) -> String {
        self.0.to_string()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has various compiler errors. For instance, you need to have a lifetime for the `&str` in `Address`: `struct Address<'a>(&'a str)`

Comment: only std can implement fat pointer. You can't

Comment: Your `From<_> for &Address` implementations don't make any sense. In order to return a reference it must be *owned* somewhere else, but you attempt to return a reference from a temporary, which won't work.

Comment: Due to the blanket `From`->`Into` impl, `impl From<X> for Y` implies `impl Into<Y> for X`. It's recommended to only ever implement `From`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably only have the following four impls:

```rust
pub struct Address(String);

impl From<String> for Address {
    fn from(s: String) -> Self {
        Self(s)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Address {
    fn from(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        Address(s.to_string())
    }
}

impl From<Address> for String {
    fn from(a: Address) -> Self {
        a.0
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a Address> for &'a str {
    fn from(a: &'a Address) -> Self {
        &a.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `String::from_utf8(Vec::from(bytes)).unwrap()` makes no sense. `bytes` in your case is already a UTF8 String, so this entire line is redundant. Did you mean bytes to be `Vec<u8>`?
- `impl From<X> for &Address` makes no sense. References don't own an object, and someone has to own the `Address` object. `impl From<X> for Address` is what you really want and already have.
- `impl Into<&str>` makes no sense, `Into` takes ownership. You can't consume an object and then return a reference to it. Again, someone has to own it. You probably want `AsRef<str>` and `Deref<Target=str>`.
- `impl Into<String> for &Address` is also unusual. `AsRef<str>` and `Deref<Target=str>` is sufficient for almost all cases, and if you want a consuming conversion, use `impl From<Address> for String`. **Never** implement `Into`, always implement `From` instead. (`From` implies `Into`)

So this is what I would do:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

pub struct Address(String);

impl From<String> for Address {
    fn from(s: String) -> Self {
        Self(s)
    }
}

impl From<&str> for Address {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self(s.to_string())
    }
}

impl AsRef<str> for Address {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl Deref for Address {
    type Target = str;

    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

// Unusual, but of course possible:
impl From<Address> for String {
    fn from(addr: Address) -> String {
        addr.0
    }
}
```

This is how to perform the conversions then, which is in line with usual Rust behaviour:

```rust
fn main() {
    // String to Address
    let s: String = "AAA".to_string();
    let _addr: Address = s.into();
    //or
    let s: String = "AAA".to_string();
    let _addr = Address::from(s);

    // &str to Address
    let s: &str = "AAA";
    let _addr: Address = s.into();
    // or
    let _addr = Address::from(s);

    // Address to &str
    let addr: Address = Address("AAA".to_string());
    let _s: &str = &addr;

    // Address to String
    let addr: Address = Address("AAA".to_string());
    let _s: String = addr.to_string();
    // Or also:
    let _s: String = addr.into();
}
```